# CSS Variables with background-image url

Tags: css, css-variables

Am I misunderstanding the capabilities of css variables? I am trying to pass a background image url to a variable like this: It seems to be working fine when I pass something simple like a color etc...

```css
:root {
  --slide-1: url(/static/images/slideshow/slide1.jpg) ;
  --slide-2: url(/static/images/slideshow/slide2.jpg) ;
  --slide-3: url(/static/images/slideshow/slide3.jpg) ;
  --slide-4: url(/static/images/slideshow/slide4.jpg) ;
  --slide-5: url(/static/images/slideshow/slide5.jpg) ;
}

//and then

.jumbotron > .jumbotron-slideshow:nth-child(1) { 
  background-image: var(--slide-1); 
}

.jumbotron > .jumbotron-slideshow:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  background-image: var(--slide-2);
}

.jumbotron > .jumbotron-slideshow:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  background-image: var(--slide-3);
}

.jumbotron > .jumbotron-slideshow:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  background-image: var(--slide-4);
}

.jumbotron > .jumbotron-slideshow:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
  background-image: var(--slide-5);
}
```

Comment: try just putting the path in your variable and using it as `.jumbotron > .blah { background-image: url(--slide-1); }` I've not used them but looks like a go'er

Comment: Looks fine to me, but you didn't include all of your code or working images so it's hard to tell what's wrong. Here's a demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaWwvz and here's [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: did you try using an absolute path instead?

Comment: @Roljhon that did it, must not be seeing the path right thank you!

Comment: @SandraWillford A great way to debug is to start with the simplest one! Goodluck buddy! :)

Comment: Note CSS variables is not implemented in Edge or IE according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=variable)

Answer (score 13):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=618165) in Chrome, the code works fine in Firefox.

You'll have to stick with absolute URLs in var() for now.

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug, but it works now.

Comment: don't work when I try to do it with base64 data url (`--example: url('data:image/png;base64,<encoded image here>')`). any workaround?

Comment: @AlexNaidovich it does work (tested in Chrome Version 80.0.3987.132):
`--detail-push-chevron: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%2012%2020'><path%20d='M2,20l-2-2l8-8L0,2l2-2l10,10L2,20z'%20fill='%23ff0000'/></svg>");`

And then: `.hasBackground { background-image: var(--detail-push-chevron); }`

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been resolved!

I also wanted to share my notes as I was building something similar:

## -- SCSS version --

In my case we were already using SCSS and needed to do exactly as OP!

SCSS helps to reduce repetitive code, which is easier to look at and great if in the future we need to add or remove slides for example.

You could go a step further and have JS pass you the number of slides as a CSS variable..

..but for this example we'll stick to OP's number of 5 slides and hardcode into SCSS like so:

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  :root { --slide-#{$i}: url(/static/images/slideshow/slide#{$i}.jpg); }

  //and then

  .jumbotron > .jumbotron-slideshow:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: #{($i - 1) * 6}s;
    background-image: var(--slide-#{$i}); 
  }
}
```