# how to add variables to background-image {url()}

Tags: css, background-image, css-variables

Im really confusion, how to add a variables in `css` in `background-image`.

```
:root {
  --image-base-url: 'https://www.xxxx.com/';
}

.banner .img{
     background-image: url(var(--image-base-url + '/images/about.jpg'));

 }
```

Here is a error. It is possible to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Variables with background-image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748998/css-variables-with-background-image-url)

Comment: @tomerpacific that question isn't relevant to this one, not a duplicate

Comment: You're trying to use JS-like concatenation in CSS. That's not currently possible.

Comment: @tomerpacific it's not a duplicate question. I saw this you mentioned it. Im asking about concat two links using variables (first link) and another link(secon link). Please open this issue.

Comment: you cannot do this, I added another relevant duplicate that explain whty