# Applying Hover Effects to React Cards with Dynamic Background Images

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, background-image

I'm working on a React project where I have a set of cards, each with a dynamic background image loaded from a JSON file. My goal is to create a hover effect on these cards, where the background image darkens, and the title and a small description appear. I've managed to make the title and description appear using opacity transitions, but I'm facing a challenge with darkening the background image because I can't directly apply a linear gradient to it using CSS. I'm looking for a simple and efficient solution to achieve this effect without making the code too complex.

Current Code:
Here's the current code structure I have for the card component:

```
const Card = ({ card }) => {
  return (
    <div className="home__prom-card" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${card.image})` }}>
      <div className="home__prom-card_price">
        <h3>{card.price}</h3>
      </div>
      <h2>{card.name}</h2>
      <p>{card.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I've encountered difficulties in applying a darkened overlay on the background image when hovering over the card. Since the background image is loaded dynamically from a JSON file, I can't directly apply a linear gradient overlay using CSS.

Comment: _"because I get the image in React code (it comes from a json file), so css can not interact with it in any way"_ - not sure what makes you think these things had anything to do with each other. You trouble with "interacting" with it is probably rather because it is set as a background image, and not as an `img` element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Darken background image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481660/darken-background-image-on-hover)

Comment: If I were assigning a background-image value inside css I would just use background-image: linear-gradient, url(). On hover. But I have to get the image from a json file, so I'm having trouble with the fade out

Comment: _"But I have to get the image from a json file"_ - okay, but that doesn't mean you have to output it _as_ the background image URL directly. [Assign the URL to a CSS variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41748998/1427878) instead (that can be done using inline style as well) - and then handle the rest via your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my approach would be to create an absolutly positioned div inside the card and use that with the background-image property.

#### Structure

The structure would look like this:

> (Created new home__prom-background div)

```
const Card = ({ card }) => {
  // home__prom-card will be changed to <Link> from React Routing soon
  return (
    <div className="home__prom-card">

      <div className="home__prom-background" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${card.image})` }} />

      <div className="home__prom-card_price">
        <h3>{card.price}</h3>
      </div>
      <h2>{card.name}</h2>
      <p>{card.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Styling

Now for the CSS part.
We add **relative** position to the card, so that the background div can use percentage for width and height to make it fit the full size. Also, we make the background black, so when the background's div opacity is be lowered, it looks darker.

When styling the background div, we set the **position** to **absolute** and the **width** and **height** to **100%**. Finally, we add some other parameters for the background and a transition for opacity.

Don't forget to set a higher **z-index** for the text, so that you can see it over the background image.

For the hover effect we will change the background div's opacity when the card is hovered. Also, we will change the opacity for the text that you want to show.

```
.home__prom-card {
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;

    > .home__prom-background {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;left: 0;
        z-index:0;

        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

        transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    }

    > h2, > p, > .home__prom-card_price {
        z-index:2;
    }

    &:hover {
        
        > .home__prom-background {
            opacity: .6;
        }

        > h2, > p {
            opacity: 1;
        }

    }

}
```